# Umbraco Surface Controller migrate from V7 to V12

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco12

I'm trying to refator the Umbraco Surfrace Controller what was written on V7 to get working on V12. The problem is that i didn't find a way to access "IPublishedContent" and also is there a way to access "CultureDictionary"? This was written a long time ago, is there a new way what is used to achive that result?(Please see the attached picture). This controller is called by Javascript. Should i have to use other type controller?

[old controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02VY4.png)

Looked the documentation, but i'm getting confused about these Surface controllers.

UPDATE: I'm able to get CurrentPage property with correct data, but only if i invoke the Surface Controller by "Html.BeginUmbracoForm", still didn't find a way to call it correctly with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved. Instead of using the `CurrentPage` property, I used this:

```
UmbracoContext.Content.GetAtRoot().FirstOrDefault()
```

This way, I'm able to get my root node and find what what is needed. If someone with more experience can confirm this workaround is okay, I will accept this answer.